# How do I resolve a fatal error in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am a Wordpress novice but am taking over the management of a site for a non-profit group.  I was on editing the site last week and things seem to be going fine.  However, when I tried to login later I received the below message.  Now all three of us that have admin access receive the same error.  I tried a simple fix of using the "lost password" approach but we are told that are account has been frozen.

Thank you for any help you are able to provide.

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context
> in /home2/mhc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/formidable/classes/controllers/FrmAddonsController.php on
> line 1048

Comment: Login to S/FTP and change name of `/home2/mhc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/formidable` folder - this will disable the plugin that is causing the problem.  Then I would backup the site and database and update all plugins and Wordpress core.

Comment: @Fresz: excellent advice.  I started a reply.  But the OP has several different problems: a) "Fatal error" on Formidable plugin, b) admins unable to login, c) "account frozen".  I was unsure which were related:  a) and b) are probably the same root cause.  And I was unsure if the OP felt comfortably with any of a) WordPress, b) WP plugins, c) the Linux filesystem, d) MySql, e) his ISP/hosting provider.  Your suggestion is a great "first step" in resolving the problem!

Comment: Thank you @paulsm4 I have updated (aka broken) a good few websites in the past. The plugin probably is up to date but something else like Wordpress is not up to date. It could also be the case that the PHP version is old (less likely).